# Rewrite variables behind folder to file outside of folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite this URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/new/agenda/2014/7/activity-1
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/new/agenda.php?year=2014&month=7&title=activity-1
```

I'm not home in `.htaccess`, but I know that it's possible, because other websites use it (eg. Wordpress). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this rule in `/new/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /new/

RewriteRule ^(agenda)/(\d+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?year=$2&month=$3&title=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```